# Adding rewrite endpoint breaks static front page

Tags: url-rewriting

I have static front page for my WP installation set from `settings > reading`. Then I have added a URL endpoint using.

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('foo', EP_ALL);
```

So, the front page should be accessible via

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/foo/bar
```

For #1 Everything works fine but for #2 and #3 default `home.php` is shown instead of static home page. Tested locally in both single and multisite installation.

Is it a desired behavior or I hit something unusual? More importantly how can I make WP to show the static homepage in the given condition?

### Solution

I was already hooking into `parse_request` to process part of code if `foo` exists. so, as per @gmazzap's solution. I only need to unset it afterwards. No need for extra hooked function is needed to bypass the bug.

```
add_action('parse_request', function(&wp){

    $key = 'foo';

    if (!array_key_exists( $key, $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // do things when foo exists

    // we no longer need 'foo'
    unset($wp->query_vars[$key]);

});
```

Comment: [Will be fixed in 4.3](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143).

Comment: ah, okey. Its a bug then. Ticket opened for 22 months! I am just glad it is fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I did not get this very well, but if you need to just remove `'foo'` from query vars would not be much more simple to use the `'request'` filter and remove the var from there?

Code needed:

```
add_filter('request', function($query_vars) {
     return array_diff_key($query_vars, array('foo'=>''));
});
```

It:

- runs on main query only
- remove the var for `$wp` object
- acts before the query is set on `$wp_query`, so no need to remove the query from there
- does not affect all the other variables

#### Edit:

A problem of this code is that it runs very early, so that it will be hard to catch the presence of the query variable and do something based on its presence / value.

A solution may be the run the conditions on the same `'request'` filter, just before remove the query var (e.g. using same hook with higer priority).

Another solution may be add a flag to `$wp` object:

```
add_filter('request', function($query_vars) {
     $GLOBALS['wp']->_foo = isset($query_vars['foo']) ? $query_vars['foo'] : false;
     return array_diff_key($query_vars, array('foo'=>''));
});
```

After that, would be possible to check the 'foo' variable in any hook fired after `'request'`, the earliest is `'parse_request'`

```
add_action('parse_request', function($wp) {
    $foo = $wp->_foo;
    // do something with foo
});
```

The last is `'shutdown'`:

```
add_action('shutdown', function() {
    $foo = $GLOBALS['wp']->_foo;
    // do something with foo
});
```

Comment: Will this remove `foo` from `$wp->query_vars` on `parse_request` action? I am running conditional code on `parse_request` when `foo` exists.

Comment: @Sisir yes, as you can see in source https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L324 `'request'` hook is fired the line before `'parse_request'`. You can move your condition to `request` hook, or maybe use `'parse_request'` to remove the variable, just after you did something based on `'foo'` presence. I also edited the A to include a third approach.

Comment: Spot on! As I am already hooking into `parse_request`. Removing `foo` from the query var after I am done with it seems more appropriate. I only need `unset($wp->query_vars['foo']);` just before I quit my hooked function in `parse_request`. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug [25143](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25143) as @toscho pointed out and will be fixed in 4.3

**Workaround Found in the ticket and modified a little**

WordPress adds `foo` as query var that causes the problem. So, we need to remove it before WP query the DB

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse191771_unset_query_arg' );
function wpse191771_unset_query_arg($query){

    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    $key = 'foo';

    $query_vars =& $query->query_vars;

    if ( array_key_exists($key, $query_vars) ) {
        // unset ref var from $wp_query
        $query->set( $key, null );

        global $wp;
        // unset ref var from $wp
        unset( $wp->query_vars[ $key ] );

        // if in home (because $wp->query_vars is empty) and 'show_on_front' is page
        if ( empty( $wp->query_vars ) && get_option( 'show_on_front' ) === 'page' ) {
            // reset and re-parse query vars
            $wp->query_vars['page_id'] = get_option( 'page_on_front' );
            $query->parse_query( $wp->query_vars );
        }
    }

}
```